# grep names from a file with only one row

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I have a file with a long row. I need to save only @names but with grep I don't get it. For example in the following text I need to save in a array the names mrvortex and MurphTWN

```
\"\/\u003e\n    @//    \u003cstrong class=\"fullname js-action-profile-name\"\u003eMartin Belanger\u003c\/strong\u003e\n   @234/       \u003cspan class=\"username js-action-profile-name\"\u003e@mrvortex\u003c\/span\u003e\n          \n      \u003c\/a\u003e\n    \u003c\/div\u003e\n      \u003cp class=\"bio \"\u003e\n          Meteorologist and Sr. Manager, TV &amp; Cross-Platform Technologies at Pelmorex Media\n      \u003c\/p\u003e\n\n    \n\n\n  \u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n\n\n\u003c\/li\u003e\n\n  \u003cli class=\"js-stream-item stream-item stream-item\n\" data-item-id=\"151623861\" id=\"stream-item-user-151623861\" data-item-type=\"user\"\u003e\n    \n\u003cdiv class=\"account  js-actionable-user js-profile-popup-actionable \" data-screen-name=\"MurphTWN\" data-user-id=\"151623861\" data-feedback-token=\"\" data-impression-id=\"\" \u003e\n    \n\n     \u003cdiv class=\"user-actions btn-group not-following  \" data-user-id=\"151623861\"\n    data-screen-name=\"MurphTWN\" data-name=\"Chris Murphy TWN\" data-protected=\"false\"\u003e\n\n\n\n    \n\n\n  \u003cbutton class=\"user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn\" type=\"button\"\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text follow-text\"\u003e\n     \u003cspan class=\"Icon Icon--follow\"\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e Seguir \n    \n  \u003c\/span\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text following-text\"\u003e\n     Siguiendo\n    \n  \u003c\/span\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text unfollow-text\"\u003e\n     Dejar de seguir\n    \n  \u003c\/span\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text blocked-text\"\u003eBloqueado\u003c\/span\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text unblock-text\"\u003eDesbloquear\u003c\/span\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text pending-text\"\u003ePendiente\u003c\/span\u003e\n  \u003cspan class=\"button-text cancel-text\"\u003eCancelar\u003c\/span\u003e\n\u003c\/button\u003e\n\n\n\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n\n\n\n  \u003cdiv class=\"content\"\u003e\n    \u003cdiv class=\"stream-item-header\"\u003e\n      \u003ca class=\"account-group js-user-profile-link\" href=\"\/MurphTWN\" \u003e\n        \u003cimg class=\"avatar js-action-profile-avatar \" src=\"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/512972504411828224\/sM3noxz7_normal.jpeg\" alt=\"\" data-user-id=\"151623861\"\/\u003e\n        \u003cstrong class=\"fullname js-action-profile-name\"\u003eChris Murphy TWN\u003c\/strong\u003e\u003cspan class=\"Icon Icon--verified Icon--small\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"u-hiddenVisually\"\u003eCuenta verificada\u003c\/span\u003e\u003c\/span\u003e\n\n          \u003cspan class=\"username js-action-profile-name\"\u003e@MurphTWN\u003c\/span\u003e\n          \n      \u003c\/a\u003e\n    \u003c\/div\u003e\n      \u003cp class=\"bio \"\u003e\n
```

Comment: Do you have `\n` in your text line, or do you have new line there?

Comment: \n is in the text line

Comment: Do you want any text after `@` like `//`, `234/`?  If not, how to select what to get?

Comment: I need to extract mrvortex from \u003e@mrvortex\ and MurphTWN from \u003e@MurphTWN\

Answer (score 1):

This may do:

```
awk -v RS="@" 'NR>1{$1=$1;n=split($1,a,"[^a-zA-Z]");if (a[1]) print a[1]}' file
mrvortex
MurphTWN
```

Or this `gnu awk` (to hit `RS="u003e@"`, gnu support multiple characters in RS):

```
awk -v RS="u003e@" 'NR>1{$1=$1;split($1,a,"[^a-zA-Z]");print a[1]}'file
mrvortex
MurphTWN
```

Comment: it helps a lot, but sometimes the name has a number, for example, mrvortex13 and I need it also

Comment: I have inserted also 0-9 in the code in order to get the numbers

Comment: @EnricAgudPique What should then mark then end of your text.

Comment: I have also insert 0-9-_   inside your code [^a-zA-Z0-9-_]

Comment: @EnricAgudPique That should do :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you need, but I believe you want to parse that long line and capture the names following `@` symbols (that are actual names, not e.g. `234`, etc..). You can use `grep -o` along with pattern matching in BASH to accomplish this. Mind you, this isn't the most elegant solution, and in the script, I read the long line from a file. (you can `cat` the line with slight modification). Let me know if you have questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

## get the long line from a file
ifn=${1:-dat/longline.txt}
[[ -f $ifn && -r $ifn ]] || { echo "Error: file not found '$ifn'"; exit 1; }

declare -a names

## grep the long line, remove leading '@', store in array
for i in $(grep -o '@[[:alpha:]]\+' -- "$ifn"); do 
    names+=( "${i#@}" )
done

## print array contents
for i in "${names[@]}"; do 
    echo "names: $i"
done
```

**output:**

```
$ bash atnames.sh
names: mrvortex
names: MurphTWN
```

Comment: David, If I have the longline.txt in the same folder I can use directly ifn=${1:-longline.txt} ?

Comment: yes, the `${1:-longline.txt}` just sets the default input file name (`ifn`) to whatever follows the `:-`. You have it correct. You can also pass it on the command line (i.e. `scriptname.sh longline.txt`) and it will take any filename that way too.

Comment: David, what does it mean tmp=${i//@/}?

Comment: An even simpler (and more efficient) way to proceed it to use positive lookbehind: the whole `for` loop can be replaced with this single line: `mapfile -t names < <(grep -Po '(?<=@)[[:alpha:]]+' -- "$ifs")`.

Comment: Thanks David for the comments